# How to plot a 3D surface from X,Y,Z array in Plotly?

Tags: python, 3d, plotly

I try to understand how to plot a 3D surace from X,Y,Z real data array. So, I've found a good sample of Plotlu 3D surface plotting:

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go

import pandas as pd

# Read data from a csv
z_data = pd.read_csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/plotly/datasets/master/api_docs/mt_bruno_elevation.csv')

fig = go.Figure(data=[go.Surface(z=z_data.values)])

fig.update_layout(title='Mt Bruno Elevation', autosize=False,
                  width=500, height=500,
                  margin=dict(l=65, r=50, b=65, t=90))

fig.show()
```

But, mt_bruno_elevation.csv data is a bit confusing for me. I don't understand what exactly data represents in csv and how to build something similar if I have an X,Y,Z array of my real data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest equation of a surface is of the form z=f(x,y). As far as I can understand, in this example, `z-data` is a 2D array. Take a look at below example;

```
 z-data = [ 
[ 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4 ],
[ 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8 ],
[ 0.9, 1.0, 1.1, 1.2 ],
[ 1.3, 1.4, 1.5, 1.6 ]
]
```

This is a z-matrix. That is those numbers are the values of y-axis for different `z` and `x`. Now the question is, what `z` and `x` are.

The first element of `z-data` ( `[ 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4 ]` ) is for constant `z=0` and different values of `x`. So (x,y,z) for the first value (0.1) equals to (0,0.1,0). For second value (0.2) is (1,0.2,0) and so on.

The second element of `z-data` ( `[ 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8 ]` ) is for constant `z=1` and different values of `x`. So (x,y,z) for the first value (0.5) equals to (0,0.5,1). For second value (0.6) is (1,0.6,1) and so on.

Helpful links:
[Link 1](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/visualize/representing-a-matrix-as-a-surface.html)
[Link 2](https://community.plotly.com/t/how-to-draw-3d-surface-chart-in-plotly-by-giving-x-y-z-axis/15567)
[Link 3](https://plotly.com/javascript/reference/#surface)